# Windows Phone WPSystem folders "security ID structure is invalid"

Tags: file-transfer, fat32, windows-phone

Background: I have an audio recording program on my Windows Phone (8.1). It stores its recordings in a private app data folder. For the longest time I've been trying to get to those files (and all other program data files). I finally thought I had solved the problem when I bought a microSD card and moved the program there on my phone. I now moved the SD card to my PC; when I show system files, I can see the WPSystem folder, which contains Apps, AppData, Etc., but now this:

When I try to open [microSD]\WPSystem\AppData or any other folder in WPSystem, I get the error message "Location is not available" "H:\WPSystem\AppData is not accessible.  The security ID structure is invalid."

When I DIR it in CMD, I get the same error "The security ID structure is invalid." PS. This is a FAT32 disk.

What can I do to get into this folder? I also have a Linux machine at work, I'll try using that next week if needed.

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP8.1 encrypts apps and app data when they're on the SD card. It's possible to get the data off, but you must do it using the phone directly unless you want useless, encrypted data.

1. Remove the `System` and `Hidden` attributes from the `D:\WPSystem` folder.

   - You may be able to do this using a PC with an SD card reader, but the phone will re-apply them sometimes.
   - I usually just use an app to do it. The app at [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/access-wpsystem-folder-t2853795) is dead simple and works. You will need to sideload the app from the PC using the application deployment tool, though; you can't just copy the .XAP file to the phone/SD card.
2. Install a file browser app on the phone. I personally like using [Aerize Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/aerize-explorer/9wzdncrfhzgn) but there are many others that work.
3. Use Storage Sense to make sure that your file management app is installed to the Phone storage, but the app you want to target (your audio storage app) is on the SD card. It will be easier to find it if that's the only app on the SD card; otherwise you may have to search a bit.
4. Open the File Management app, and add the SD card (`D:\`) so you can browse it. Make sure the `D:\WPSystem` folder is visible; if not, you need to unhide the folder again (as in step #1).
5. Go into `D:\WPSystem\AppData` and find the data folder for your app. Copy it to another location on the SD card. While all data written to the `WPSystem` folder gets encrypted, it is transparently decrypted on read and not re-encrypted if it is written/copied to a location outside of the `WPSystem` folder.
6. You should now be able to access your extracted data using the on-phone file browser app or by removing the SD card and putting it in a PC.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I'm stuck on step 1. On my PC, the "Hidden" attribute box is greyed out, and I don't see where to take off the System attribute. On my phone, I can't get the app sideloaded (the Store doesn't show any option to install local apps).

Comment: BTW, my phone currently isn't developer unlocked. I'm planning to try unlocking it soon though--seems like it should make these things a lot easier.

Comment: As I said, you can't just put the XAP file on the phone, you *must* dev-unlock and use the deployment tool. For doing it with a PC, you have to remove the System and Hidden attributes at the same time. I'm not sure if this is possible via the GUI, but it's easy from CMD: `attrib -S -H D:\WPSystem` (adjust path as needed for your PC).

Comment: I was finally able to get the phone dev unlocked and get the files copied. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem. I accidentally dropped a zip file at WpSystem on my Windows 10 and I can't do anything with the file. I need this file and every attempt of move or copy throws me this message: The security ID structure is invalid